C# .net core 8.0 what is used to play mp3 files?
I moved the code from .net 4.8 to .net core 8.0 and found an error in the AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer section.


Is there an alternative to AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer?
 private AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWindowsMediaPlayer1;
 this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1 = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();


As seen in the documentation:  The feature associated with this page, Windows Media Player SDK, is a legacy feature. It has been superseded by MediaPlayer. MediaPlayer has been optimized for Windows 10 and Windows 11. Microsoft strongly recommends that new code use MediaPlayer instead of Windows Media Player SDK, when possible. Microsoft suggests that existing code that uses the legacy APIs be rewritten to use the new APIs if possible.

Search on nuget

Your old code was using a generated COM wrapper and that's an indicator of legacy code before .NET Framework 3.0 where Microsoft officially introduced a MediaPlayer class with WPF. Please read the linked thread to learn how to use that in your .NET 8 project.

There's a nice library called Raylib that supports audio.
You might be able to use:
Music music = LoadMusicStream(fileName); // Load music stream from file
PlayMusicStream(music);
while (shouldPlayMusic)
{
    UpdateMusicStream(music);
}

UnloadMusicStream(music);
CloseAudioDevice();

You can read more about it here.
You can add Raylib to your project through NuGet.

Raylib is predominantly a C library. There are C# bindings, but it still feels like C, with all the issues that entails.

I agree, but I also think that for this particular use case (audio), the c# bindings don't pose a significant source of bugs.
